# Laravel not showing the new changes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ftp

Any idea on this? I am currently using Laravel 4.2.

We have an existing web application already running in live. Something needs to be changed so I downloaded all the files from live server to my localhost via ftp and do the update in there. Everything is working fine in localhost but when I tried to upload(ftp) the select files (that were only updated- a blade file, a controller and a model), and and test the live site, the changes aren't showing. Checked the html elements thru browser dev tools and indeed it's just the old version. The id that I newly added in the div isn't there.

I checked in the filemanager if the files were successfully updated and it's there.

I am done doing the following:
cleared my browser cache, cleared files in /app/storage/views. What else to do?

Is updating the files thru FTP for laravel not good? Honestly I am just a newbie to this framework so your explicit explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: make sure you are overwriting the files, and are overwriting them in the correct place! Also, try restarting your server software.

Comment: I think OP uses shared hosting and can not restart anything, just upload files. But general advice is correct I guess overwrite correct files. jn16 you can try uploading some text file like test.txt to public/createnewfolder/ and see if you get there http://example.com/createnewfolder/test.txt

Comment: same problem any one solved it by the way ??

Answer (score 3):

Laravel compiles all files before they are deployed  most times. If the files are not recompiled on the server, then it's gonna keep running the old setup. if you have terminaal access,  running`php artisan clear-compiled` may fix your problem. I may be wrong but this is what i see from where i'm sitting.